# Scala syntax errors when building Spark

Tags: apache-spark

I cloned a fresh copy of the `branch-2.0` branch of Spark from Github onto a Centos 7 system. When executing the [suggested](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/building-spark.html) command to build from source,

`./dev/make-distribution.sh --name custom-spark --tgz -Psparkr -Phadoop-2.4 -Phive -Phive-thriftserver -Pyarn`

I get the following errors:

```
[INFO] Total time: 5.368 s (Wall Clock)
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-08-18T11:56:49-05:00
[error[INFO] Final Memory: 71M/1963M
] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
/home/rprechelt/ada/spark/common/tags/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/annotation/Since.scala:30: error writing class Since: /home/rprechelt/ada/spark/common/tags/target/scala-2.11/classes/org/apache/spark/annotation/Since.class: /home/rprechelt/ada/spark/common/tags/target/scala-2.11/classes/org is not a directory
[error] private[spark] class Since(version: String) extends StaticAnnotation
[error]                      ^
[error] /home/rprechelt/ada/spark/common/tags/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/annotation/package.scala:25: error writing package object annotation: /home/rprechelt/ada/spark/common/tags/target/scala-2.11/classes/org/apache/spark/annotation/package.class: /home/rprechelt/ada/spark/common/tags/target/scala-2.11/classes/org is not a directory
[error] package object annotation
[error]                ^
[error] two errors found
[error] Compile failed at Aug 18, 2016 11:56:49 AM [0.358s]
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal net.alchim31.maven:scala-maven-plugin:3.2.2:compile (scala-compile-first) on project spark-sketch_2.10: Execution scala-compile-first of goal net.alchim31.maven:scala-maven-plugin:3.2.2:compile failed. CompileFailed -> [Help 1]
```

I'm at a loss for what could be occurring here - I've tried building it with different versions of Scala, but they all report the same error.

Does anyone have any suggestions about how I might go about fixing this?

Comment: Is the sufficient free space? Type "df /home" to check.

Comment: Yes - this is running on an enterprise server with 12TB of disk space. `df` reports less than 1% is used.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem, this is because zinc server is started by some other user. Trying killing zinc and then starting the build again.

Its basically an access error where zinc server started by another user is trying to write to a different directory.

```
sudo ps -ef | grep zinc
```